# Office professional plus

Tags: microsoft-office, multiple-users

Office professional plus I've   just installed on my laptop their are three of us who use laptop but only I'm able to use office not the others how do I enable office on their accounts

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I agree with harrymc, after doing so, other users can open Office apps via going to the installation root directory, find the executable programs of Office apps, such as winword, excel and others. Then send the shortcuts to their desktop.

Comment: Who is the software licensed to? Are these Microsoft accounts and a subscription to Office 365, or a full software license? What version of Office?

Answer (score 2):

For Office to be available to all users,
you need to install it using an Administrator account.

If you install it as a user, only that user will be able to use it.